# combine two comma seperated txt file file in python

Tags: python

i am trying to combine two txt files together. this is what i have so far

```
fileLake = open("lakes.txt", "r")  # has two columns
listLake = []
for lay in fileLake:
    line = lay.strip().split(",")
    nameLake = line[0]
    waterQuality = line[1]
    listLake = nameLake, waterQuality
    print(listLake)
      
    
    
filePortage = open("portages.txt", "r") # has three columns 

for ages in filePortage:
    inLand = ages.strip().split(",")
    lake1 = inLand[0]
    lake2 = inLand[1]
    distance = inLand[2]
    data = lake1, lake2, distance
    
    
    
     result = data, listLake
     print(result)
```

the output should be something like this

```
manomin, winnanage, 0.6, upper, good
```

but for some reason i keep getting the last input of the lakes combining with each line of the portage file like this

```
(('Manomin', ' Winnange', ' 0.6'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Winnange', ' Upper Stewart', ' 0.8'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Lower Stewart', ' Upper Stewart', ' 0.1'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Lower Stewart', ' Geejay', ' 0.4'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Manomin', ' Geejay', ' 0.75'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Crabclaw', ' Winnange', ' 1.25'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Crabclaw', ' Eagle', ' 0.35'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('Falcon', ' West Hawk', ' 1.7'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
(('West Hawk', ' Caddy', ' 2.4'), ('Caddy', ' average'))
```

can someone explain, what i am doing wrong here

thank you

Comment: please share some data from text files as well

Comment: By output, do you mean another csv file?

Comment: It is because you are REPLACING `listLake` each time through the loop, not ADDING to it.  You want `listLake.append( (nameLake, waterQuality))`, but that doesn't really solve the problem.  If the two files have the same number of lines, you can use `zip` to run through them both at once.  I'll show you in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASSUMING the two files have the same number of lines, this will do it:

```
fileLake = open("lakes.txt", "r")  # has two columns
filePortage = open("portages.txt", "r") # has three columns 

for line1,line2 in zip(fileLake.readlines(), filePortage.readlines()):
    lake = line1.strip().split(",")
    port = line2.strip().split(",")
    print( ",".join(lake + port) )
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of fixing the issue.

The thing that you are doing wrong is : first iterating over the filesLake and in line 7 the last element of the list(of file elements) is being assigned to listLake, so in 2nd last line listLake will have only one element and that is getting added for every element of other file(because we are in loop of second file)

FIX :
In line 7 : replace `listLake = nameLake, waterQuality`
with `listLake.append(tuple(nameLake, waterQuality))`

do the same in second loop, for `data` list -> append tuple of data
and then concat both the lists in second last line(keep it outside the 2nd loop)
`result = data + listLake`

Not performing any other checks.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it prints tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2 error